# SQL function REGEXP_SUBSTR: Regular Expression how to get the content between two characters but not include them

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

For these strings

```
   RSLR_AIRL19_ID3454_T20030913091226
   RSLR_AIRL19_ID3122454_T20030913091226
   RSLR_AIRL19_ID34_T20030913091226
```

How to get the number after ID ?

Or how to get the content between two characters but not include them ?

I use this `'/\_ID([^_]+)/'` got matches like Array ( [0] => _ID3454 [1] => 3454 )

Is this the right way?

Comment: What ***flavor*** of regular expression? What defines "the number after ID"? Is it the series of digits after "ID" and prior to "_"?

Comment: One can use capturing named or numbered groups, but the syntax may vary depending on the programming language and regex engine. What is the programming language you're using?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @Sina IN pl/sql REGEXP_SUBSTR()

Comment: @Frank: To improve the question, **edit** the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract a number after an `ID`, you could write a similar query.

```
SQL> with t1 as(
  2    select 'RSLR_AIRL19_ID3454_T20030913091226' as col from dual union all
  3    select 'RSLR_AIRL19_ID3122454_T20030913091226'     from dual union all
  4    select 'RSLR_AIRL19_ID34_T20030913091226'          from dual
  5  )
  6  select regexp_substr(col, '^([[:alnum:]]+_){2}ID([[:digit:]]+)_([[:alnum:]]+){1}$', 1, 1, 'i', 2) as ID
  7    from t1
  8  ;

ID
-------------
3454
3122454
34
```

Or, if you want to extract digits from a first occurrence of the pattern without verifying if an entire string matches a specific format:

```
SQL> with t1 as(
  2    select 'RSLR_AI_RL19_ID3454_T20030913091226' as col from dual union all
  3    select 'RSLR_AIRL19_ID3122454_T20030913091226'      from dual union all
  4    select 'RSLR_AIRL19_ID34_T20030913091226'           from dual
  5  )
  6  select regexp_substr(col, 'ID([[:digit:]]+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1) as ID
  7    from t1
  8  ;

ID
--------------
3454
3122454
34
```

Answer (score 0):

With [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) & [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) engines :

```
ID\K\w+
```

**NOTE**

`\K` "restart" the match.

See http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/pcre-regex-spotlight-k (`php` use `pcre`)